# ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> has no values

Tags: java, json, string, arraylist, hashmap

My `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songslist` has no values in it. In my `doInBackground` method i have for-loop that should fill this ArrayList. The Strings "id", "interpret"... have also values in it. Where is the problem? Here the code:

```
JSONArray charts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CHARTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for(int i=0;i<charts.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = charts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = json_data.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String interpret = json_data.getString(TAG_INTERPRET);
                    String titel = json_data.getString(TAG_TITEL);
                    String album = json_data.getString(TAG_ALBUM);
                    String albumcover = json_data.getString(TAG_ALBUMCOVER);
                    String likes = json_data.getString(TAG_LIKES);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_INTERPRET, interpret);
                    map.put(TAG_TITEL, titel);
                    map.put(TAG_ALBUM, album);
                    map.put(TAG_ALBUMCOVER, albumcover);
                    map.put(TAG_LIKES, likes);       

                    songslist.add(map);

                }
```

but List is empty. The JSONArray includes the values.

Comment: do you debug this??? probably charts.length() == 0

Comment: It's not entering in loop. @Nullpo is right.

Answer (score 2):

The code that creates the map and puts the elements in the list is ok.  So its either

1) `songslist` is messed up.  You don't show where/how its created
2) you think `charts` has items in it, but it doesn't.

Comment: i will post the full method...

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songslist;

songslist is created int the ShowCharts activity above the OnCreate

Answer (score 2):

You're not entering into the loop. Your posted code its OK. charts.length() == 0

Comment: i go into the loop, when i debug interpret, id etc. have values, but just skips the lines after hashmap..

Comment: Before "songslist.add(map);", put "System.out.println(songlist)" and copy that console line, please.

Comment: I cant use System.out.println(songlist) in this way...im developing for Android and it seems to be a bit more difficult to print out because "Log.d" doenst work for (String, ArrayList)

Comment: After String likes = json_data.getString(TAG_LIKES); Eclipse directly jump into my:
`public void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
         // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
         pDialog.dismiss();
         // updating UI from Background Thread
         
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 /**
                  * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                  * */
                 LazyAdapter adapter = new LazyAdapter(ShowCharts.this, songslist);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
             }
         });`

Comment: I believe that the problem isn't in the code.

Clean your project (Project -> clean -> OK). Delete the app into your android device, and debug it again :).

Comment: i set a breakpoint to songslist.add(map); because its the next possibility, but eclipse doenst stop there...

Comment: Ok...srsly! The Code is correct. I just tried to comment out the lines from "String interpret" to "string likes.." so i have just the code line:
String id = json_data.getString(TAG_ID);

I set a breakpoint to "Hashmap...." and songslist.add(map); and suddenly eclipse doenst skip the lines and my device shows a list to me. Moreover, the eclipse doesnt skip, when i delete one string e.g. Likes.

Comment: Ok...ok...i found the problem. So dumb!! I forgot to set a place for my id in my adapter. So the adpater had a value too much, so that he doenst know what to do with the last value... -.-

Comment: Take it easy.... Sith happens: http://i284.photobucket.com/albums/ll16/draikoh/star-wars-sith-happens.jpg